# Jerks when drawing a graph in real time with Android GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am writing app with realtime plotting data from sensors on my android phone.
For realtime plotting I use GraphView library and method `appendData`.
I get data point by point from sensors in my BroadcastReceiver and after that call method `appendData`.

```
private BroadcastReceiver sensorsDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == BROADCAST_ACTION) {
            if (intent.getIntExtra(MyService.SENSOR_TYPE, 9999) == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                float[] data = intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MyService.SENSOR_DATA);
                mAccelerometerSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(mGraphXAxisSamples[0]++, data[0]), false, 600);
            } else if (intent.getIntExtra(MyService.SENSOR_TYPE, 9999) == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                float[] data = intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MyService.SENSOR_DATA);
                mGyroscopeSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(mGraphXAxisSamples[1]++, data[0]), false, 600);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The main problem is - plot is updated by jerks (with pauses). The graph is updated in real time to the 8th point, and then there is a delay, after which another eight points are drawn (up to 16) at a one time. The same after the 20th, etc.

Addition:

Also I tried (HB advice) wrap `appendData` in `Handler` with delay:

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAccelerometerSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(mGraphXAxisSamples[0]++, data[0]), false, 600);
                    }
                }, 100);
```

But it does not change the situation :(

Comment: Try adding your logic in a `Handler`

Comment: You are mean `Handler` for main UI-thread?

Comment: I mean a `Handler` with a `Runnable` so that you can use `postDelayed` of let's say 100ms. This will help to add the data gradually instead of adding it all at once.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it doesn't help me :( (See addition on my edited post)